# Nightlight not working after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: 22.04, night-light

Today I upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 from 20.04 and the nightlight / bluelight filter isn't working anymore.

It shows as turned on in in Settings menu but isn't changing anything.

How do I diagnose and/or fix this?

[image]

Comment: Seems it resolved by itself after I logged out and back in, no idea why though not sure where to find logs for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happened on a fresh restart, but after logging out and logging back it it began to work with no changes made.